# How to insert fraction symbols in database like ¼, ½ etc

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, server

I saved some long text in my database. That text also contains some fraction symbols like ¼, ½ etc. When I try to retrieve that text in my android app, no text appears and then I remove the fraction symbols from text then data shows correctly.
I want to ask how I can save these symbols in the database and retrieve properly to use in-app.
Thanks

Comment: Make sure the encoding supports those symbols

Comment: I'm new in this field so can you please explain about encoding support?

Comment: Google is your friend https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset.html

Comment: Also a option would be to encode those to html entries. like `&frac14` for `1/4`

Comment: https://fractal-signs.net/